# Css selector : parent and child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Pls somebody should guide me out  by briefly explaining what is meant by parent element or child element in css. I had read alot of tutorial on css selector where this terms are always mention, e.g first-child element, parent element, child of thesame parent e.t.c 
please in a set of html element, which of them is parent or child.
And if brother, uncle, nephew or cousin of element also exist pls include them in your answers THANK YOU ALL IN ADVANCE

Comment: Where are you stuck? I look at this and think you're maybe asking for guidance on interpreting the English language, rather than asking a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

I find it hard to believe that this is not clear to anyone, but here goes.

*Ancestors* are elements that are **parents** or grand-parents (or great-grand-parents and so on). This means they are higher in the HTML structure. Compare it to your family. Your father is your parent, his father is his parent *and* your grand-parent, and so on. You are the child of your father.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

When considering the first element of a set of children, that is called [**`first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and can be selected as such with CSS3. For instance, in this HTML:

```
<ul id="parent">
  <li>First list item</li>
  <li>Second list item</li>
  <li>Third list item</li>
</ul>
```

combined with this CSS:

```
li:first-child {color: red;}
```

the first list item "First list item" will be in a red color, but the other list items won't. All the `li`'s are children (or "child elements") of the same parent, which is the `ul` with ID "parent". The list items are each others' **siblings**, they are brothers and sisters if you will.

With the same logic, [**`:last-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selects the last child in the set. So with this CSS

```
li:last-child {color: blue;}
```

the last item in the list, i.e. "Third list item", will be in a blue color. You can see `:first-child` and `:last-child` in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqph4c7y/).

### BE WARNED THOUGH!

In some cases, you might need to use [**`:first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) instead of `:first-child`! You see, first-child selects the first child no matter what type it is, whereas first-of-type, as the name suggests, selects the first element of that type.

The following HTML explains it.

```
<div id="parent">
  <span class="child">I am the first child and also the first of type "span"!</span>
  <span class="child">I am neither the first child, but second, nor first of type "span" :(</span>
  <span class="child">I am neither the first child, but third, nor first of type "span" :(</span>
  <blockquote class="child">I might not be the first child, but fourth, but I am the first of my type "blockquote!" Funny enough, I am also the last of my type!</blockquote>
  <span class="child">And I am just sitting here, being the last-child and the last of my type "span"</span>
</div>
```

See it in action in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqph4c7y/1/)!

Answer (score 0):

the parent/child denomination refers to the html structure. elements can be nested in each other. in the following example the two divs are in the first div. they are both children of the containing div. the containing div it the parent of the children.

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

- 1 is parent of 2
- 2 is child of 1
- 2 is first child of 1